# NuxtLink & GraphQL mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

I am trying to create Nuxt application with GraphQL + Apollo Server connection. I'm just starting my Nuxt practice and I have a problem. When the page is reloaded, the date is retrieved at the start via useMutation:

```
const { mutate: postPublish, loading } = useMutation(PUBLISH_POST, {
  variables: {
    postId: props.id,
  },
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: GET_PROFILE,
      variables: {
        userId: params.id,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

When switching between pages, I use the recommended `<NuxtLink></NuxtLink>`;
but when switching pages in this way, useMutation does not trigger on startup.
Everything works when I'm using `<a></a>` tag.

Can someone explain to me why it works like this and how to remedy it by staying with `<NuxtLink></NuxtLink>`